# Summing numeric attributes of field during Spatial Join using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join

Just performed a spatial join operation on a polygon layer (made of 500 grids cells) and point layer (1 million points). The aim was to find the sum of a  field in the points layer (field AREA) during the spatial join process. However, the result of the spatial join output shows 0 for all the rows. Below is the code used.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

point = r"C:\Example\Scratch.gdb\trees"
grid = r"C:\Example\Scratch.gdb\grid"
grid_join = r"C:\Example\Scratch.gdb\grid_join"


#Make feature layers
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(point, "point_lyr")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(grid, "grid_lyr")

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("point_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", """ "TYPE" = 'Mangrove' """)
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("point_lyr", "in_memory", "tree_new")
tree_new = r'in_memory\tree_new'


arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(grid, tree_new, grid_join, "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL", "AREA \"AREA\" true true true 8 Double 6 7 ,Sum,#,C:\\Example\\Scratch.gdb\\in_memory\\tree_new,AREA,-1,-1", "COMPLETELY_CONTAINS", "", "")
```

Comment: What's treeCenter_C in the last line(spatialJoin). you create a new layer named "treeCenter_C" as a string ? Does selectbylocation selects any feature?

Comment: I apologise for the typographical error. That's corrected now. tree_new is the temporary layer saved in memory.

Comment: What's the result of Select by attribute?

Comment: It shows the trees classed as Mangrove. This is a unique class of interest amongst five other classes.

Comment: AREA is a reserved word, have a look for AREA_1 (or 2 or _1_1) in your table and see if that matches your point AREA field then use Summary Statistics http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001z000000 to find the sum of AREA_X fields for each unique polygon ID (Statistics field AREA_X : Type SUM, Case field of polygon ID).